# How much time can be taken inside onDestroy() before the activity is killed?

Tags: android, android-activity, destroy

I know my question caption must have sounded really vague. But let me clear it out here.

Say I have an android application over a middleware stack. In onCreate() of my activity, I initialise my middleware modules.

In its onDestroy(), I must de-initialise the middleware. Now my middleware calls may take quite some time to process. So I want to know how much time the onDestroy() function has, and see whether my deinitialisation can take place within that time.

Is it reasonable to keep my de-init in the onDestroy()?

Also, suppose I initialise the middleware in onCreate() of activity A1. On a button click, activity A1 switches to activity A2. In low memory situations, the LMK will kill the activity that has not been in use for some time. In such a case, won't activity A1 be killed? When activity A1 is killed, will all instances I create in A1 also get destoryed?

Regards,
kiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are rather confused to ask this question.

In order to get a good comprehension of what is happening, you should take a look at the lifecycle graphs that can be found on developer.android.com:

- [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks)
- [Background service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#LifecycleCallbacks)

You will see that `Activity.onDestroy()` only gets called in the case of a controlled shutdown of the activity - something that happens extremely rarely, as the Android OS can kill your process in a variety of states without ever calling your `onDestroy()` method.

What and why do you need to de-initialize?

- If you're worried about releasing resources, then most of them will get released anyway when/if your process is killed.
- If you are worried about saving the user's data (your application's state) then you should override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`

If you really want an answer to your question, then here it is:

- While it is running `onDestroy()`, your app has (probably) as much time as it would like to - the fact that it is even running `onDestroy()` means that the OS did not select it to be killed. But it will most likely not matter: for one, `onDestroy` will never be run in most apps, and if the OS changes its mind and decides that your app must die, it will kill it even if it is running `onDestroy`.

Comment: @jhominal: A small note regarding when to save the user's data. One should be aware that `onSaveInstanceState()` only will be called if the application is being killed by the system. It will _not_ be triggered if the application exits due to the user either pressing the back button, or `finish()` being called in your code. So if you want to be 100% sure that you save the current application state, this should be done in `onPause()`.

Comment: And another note: when you say `your app has (probably) as much time as it would like to`, this is not correct. If your app had as much time as it would like, it could easily freeze up the whole system. So the 5-second rule still goes.

Comment: @Nailuj: The app runs in its own Linux process. If it begins to consume too much resources in the `onDestroy` method, (the user has already left the app), the process will be unceremoniously killed by the system - but the condition for that to occur should be tied to a quantity of consumed resources rather than a specific duration.

Comment: Another note: The "5 second rule" is in no way universal. It simply says: "If your app takes more than 5 seconds to react to user input, then I (Android) will show the user a dialog to kill you." Nothing more, nothing less: your app could consume no resources at all and still suffer that rule (for example by calling `sleep` on the UI thread). But in a call to `onDestroy`, your app has not been responsible for user input for some time, so it does not apply.

Comment: @jhominal: ok, I can see that it might not be a strict 5-second rule for performing your work, but to say that you have as much time as you'd like is probably a bit off as well - since you have no guarantee that the system won't kill the process if it is in need of resources.

Comment: @Nailuj: I could have phrased it better by saying that there was no time limit for how long `onDestroy` could run. Added a bit at the end to clear misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html:

> In Android, the system guards against
>   applications that are insufficiently
>   responsive for a period of time by
>   displaying a dialog to the user,
>   called the Application Not Responding
>   (ANR) dialog

The ANR dialog will normally pop up if your application is un-responsive for 5 seconds. As pointed out by jhominal, the `onDestroy()` method is probably not where you want to do your clean-up/save preferences/etc.

Regardless of where you choose to do this, be it `onDestroy()`, `onSaveInstanceState()` or in `onPause()`, I believe the general 5 second rule will apply. If what you're doing takes more than 5 seconds, the ANR dialog will show and the user can choose to force-close your app.

*Edit:*
If your application is in the background, it might be (probably?) that it is killed directly without the ANR dialog being displayed if you violate the 5 second rule. But I do not know this for sure, only assuming.